# R Markdown repeatable plain text with embedded fields

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, reporting

I'm working on a structured report. That is I want the output to consist of some template text with embedded R. An example section:

```
*ID:* **`r bl$ID[41]`**  *CR Name:* **`r bl$Name[41]`**  
*Business Unit:* **`r bl$BusinessUnit[41]`**  
*Business POC:* **`r bl$BusinessContact[41]`**   
*Current State:* **`r bl$Status[41]`**  
*Analyst:* **`r bl$Analyst[41]`**  
*Developer:* **`r bl$Developer[41]`**  
*QA Tester:* **`r bl$QATester[41]`**  
*UAT Tester:* **`r bl$UAT[41]`**  

*Test Environment:* **`r bl$TestBed[41]`**  

**Description:**  
`r bl$Description[41]`  

**Comments:**  
`r bl$Comments[41]`
```

It's a simple matter to insert single data elements this way (hard coding the value in the square brackets), but I have been looking on and off for several days for a way of generating multiples of this structure with different value for each template.

That is to say, I'm looking for a means of repeating the template text while varying the values in the square brackets.

There is a wealth of material on generating tables, but I can't figure out how to apply any of it to this situation. Am I missing something obvious? Have any of you done something like this?

Thanks for your interest.

Here's my code. Of course, the setwd() will have to be adjusted. I have provided one row of data and the headers.

````
---
title: "TableExperimental"
output: 
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
setwd("~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents")
```

```{r status_chart, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, output="asis"}
library("data.table")
library("glue")

bl <- fread("dummyCRs.tab")

bl$DateCreated <- as.Date(bl$DateCreated, "%Y-%m-%d")
bl$BacklogRank[is.na(bl$BacklogRank)] <- "Not Yet Ranked"
bl$Priority <- factor(bl$Priority, levels = c("Not Yet Ranked", "5","4","3","2","1"))
bl$Status <- factor(bl$Status, levels = c("unknown", "draft", "analysis", "development","unit test", "QA", "UAT", "deployed", "closed", "withdrawn"))
bl$BusinessUnit <- factor(bl$BusinessUnit)
bl$TestBed <- factor(bl$TestBed)
bl$CurrentSprint <- factor(bl$CurrentSprint)
bl$Developer <- factor(bl$Developer)
bl$Analyst <- factor(bl$Analyst)
bl$QATester <- factor(bl$QATester)
bl$UATtester <- factor(bl$QATester)    

glue('ID: {bl$ID[41]}   Name: {bl$Name[41]}')
glue('Date created: {bl$DateCreated[41]}')
glue('Business Unit: {bl$BusinessUnit[41]}  Contact: {bl$BusinessContact[41]}')
glue('Analyst: {bl$Analyst[41]}')
glue('Developer: {bl$Developer[41]}')
glue('QA Tester: {bl$QATester[41]}')
glue('UAT: {bl$UAT[41]}')
glue('')
glue('Description:')
glue('{bl$Description[41]}')
glue('Comments:')
glue('{bl$Comments[41]}')
glue('')
glue('')
```


*ID:* **`r bl$ID[41]`**  *CR Name:* **`r bl$Name[41]`** 
<!-- *Business Unit:* **`r bl$BusinessUnit[41]`**
<!-- *Business POC:* **`r bl$BusinessContact[41]`**
<!-- *Current State:* **`r bl$Status[41]`**
<!-- *Analyst:* **`r bl$Analyst[41]`**
<!-- *Developer:* **`r bl$Developer[41]`**
<!-- *QA Tester:* **`r bl$QATester[41]`**
<!-- *UAT Tester:* **`r bl$UAT[41]`**

<!-- *Test Environment:* **`r bl$TestBed[41]`** 

<!-- **Description:**
<!-- `r bl$Description[41]`

<!-- **Comments:**
<!-- `r bl$Comments[41]`
````

Minimal data set:

```
ID  DateCreated Name    CRDocURL    Status  Description BusinessUnit    CurrentSprint   BacklogRank Comments    BusinessContact Developer   Analyst QATester    UAT TestBed
525 2017-09-03  CR525_ponvds    CR Doc  development At vel nobis comprehensam, pro ea agam intellegat repudiandae, no indoctum partiendo usu. Expetendis reformidans no quo, te autem propriae sed. Duo fierent qualisque omittantur ad,    Accounting  TRUE        Quocumque igitur a uobis deieci oculos, partim ignaua segnities partim callidus liuor occurrit, ut contumeliam uideatur diuinis tractatibus inrogare    McGoo, Quincy   Neff, Walter    Dietrichson, Phyllis    Schmoe, Joe Keyes, Bart DVLP10
```

Comment: Did you try the [`glue` package](http://glue.tidyverse.org/)?

Comment: No, I didn't. That seems like the perfect solution. I'll write a function to output the text using glue, the apply it to the rows of the table. I always look for a tricky solution when a straightforward one like this is just what's needed. Thank you!

Comment: Round 2: This doesn't do what I need, unfortunately. I have two problems with the output. 1) every line is preceded with "##" 2) the output is presented on a gray background. In the initial sample code I showed, the values of the the variables were inserted into the static text in such a way that it doesn't shout "CODE OUTPUT HERE!!!"

Comment: Please excuse the formatting. I don't know how to

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `glue_data()` function. Here's an example with your minimal dataset.

````
---
title: "TableExperimental"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r status_chart, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"}
library(glue)
library(magrittr)

bl <- data.frame(
  ID = 525L, 
  DateCreated = "2017-09-03", 
  Name = "CR525_ponvds", 
  CRDocURL = "CR Doc", 
  Status = "development", 
  Description = "At vel nobis comprehensam, pro ea agam intellegat repudiandae, no indoctum partiendo usu. Expetendis reformidans no quo, te autem propriae sed. Duo fierent qualisque omittantur ad,", 
  BusinessUnit = "Accounting", 
  CurrentSprint = TRUE, 
  BacklogRank = NA, 
  Comments = "Quocumque igitur a uobis deieci oculos, partim ignaua segnities partim callidus liuor occurrit, ut contumeliam uideatur diuinis tractatibus inrogare", 
  BusinessContact = "McGoo, Quincy", Developer = "Neff, Walter", 
  Analyst = "Dietrichson, Phyllis", QATester = "Schmoe, Joe", 
  UAT = "Keyes, Bart", 
  TestBed = "DVLP10",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

bl %>%
  glue_data(
    'ID: {ID}   Name: {Name}  \n',
    'Date created: {DateCreated}  \n',
    'Business Unit: {BusinessUnit}  Contact: {BusinessContact}  \n', 
    'Analyst: {Analyst}  \n', 
    'Developer: {Developer}  \n', 
    'QA Tester: {QATester}  \n', 
    'UAT: {UAT}  \n  \n', 
    'Description:  \n', 
    '{Description}  \n', 
    'Comments:  \n', 
    '{Comments}'
  )
```
````

Comment: That's much closer. So, if I wrap it in any apply() function, that should process all the rows in my data frame. Is that how you see it? And thanks again!

Comment: No need. Use on your real data. The function `glue_data` will do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've worked out all the kinks and the program is ready to demo to my boss.